# Issue when trying to connect to mssql using Django

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I'm trying to connect my mssql to my Django project. I've tried using pyodbc outside of the project and that works. But when i'll try to connect inside the project it doesn't work.. I have tried "mssql-django" and "pyodbc-django". The error i get is:

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute
> (0)')

At the driver string i have also tried, "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server".

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "mssql",
        "NAME": "####",
        "USER": "####",
        "PASSWORD": "####",
        "HOST": "####",
        "PORT": "",
        "OPTIONS": {"driver": "SQL Server", ## "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: `SQL Server` is the name for the old, deprecated and no longer supplied _SQL Server Native Client_ driver that was specific to Windows hosts and hasn't had any active feature development since SQL Server 2012 was a thing. What is your host operating system? Which version(s) of ODBC Driver for SQL Server do you have installed?

Comment: I have ODBC Driver 18 installed on my pc, but when i use "SQL Server" with pyodbc outside of the project i get an connection.